# Class design of overriding styling in C#

Tags: c#, design

I have a requirement in which at different hierarchy in a xml each node have similar set of properties. But every parent can override its child settings. Its just like the CSS styling over the html element in reverse order.

For example

```
<Node1>
 <settings>
      ..... Some common properties
 </settings>

      <Node2>
         <settings>
              ..... Some common properties
         </settings>
      </Node2>

           <Node3>
               <settings>
                 ..... Some common properties
             </settings>
         </Node3>
</Node1>
```

So I am wondering which design should I follow. How I can start writing the classes. Any help please?

I am working with C#.

Comment: `Settings` class where all nodes classes use it as a property

Comment: Design classes based on how you will use them. But you don't show a usage examples

Comment: One thing which we trying to achieve is :
Suppose I provided some settings for "Node 3" in above example through some UI,
Now on "Node 2" I can override those settings and similarly on "Node 1" I can override the settings on "Node 2"

And in other UI I can show the styles applied on any given node including the overriding properties.

Comment: That mean you actually don't care how setting s will be stored/represented. But important how you will read them when generating a view. If you start from "Node1", you apply all settings, then for "Node2" apply only settings which wasn't applied in "Node1" and so on for "Node3"

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking on the similar lines but was looking for some standard if any in such scenarios. Thanks by the way.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you designing an object model, or are you writing an XML parser?

Comment: I was designing Object model and serialize it to XML at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Since the parent settings override the child settings and you'll encounter the parent settings first as you traverse the tree, this is easily solved with a `Dictionary<TSettingName, TSettingValue>`. As you encounter a setting, check if it already exists in the dictionary. If not, add it. That way, the parent value gets added if present and the child one is ignored.

Comment: Or `Hash<TSettingName>` if don't care about value since it is already applied

Comment: Note that you could also use a recursive method, but **first** process the child node, **then** process the local properties. This ensures that a parent will override its children (where specified).